# Reason for Validation loss is going high?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I'm very new to deep learning models, and trying to train a multi-label classifying text model using LSTM .I have around 2600 records which has 4 categories.Using 80% for train and rest for validations.

There is nothing complex in code i.e am reading csv, tokenizing the data and feeding to model.
But after 3-4 epochs validation loss becomes greater than 1 whereas train_loss tends to zero.As far as i searched it is the case of over fitting. To overcome this, i tried with different layers,changing the units.But still problem remains as it is.
If i stop at 1-2 epochs, then predictions get's wrong.

Below is my model creation code:-

```
ACCURACY_THRESHOLD = 0.75
class myCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback): 
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}): 
        print(logs.get('val_accuracy'))
        fname='Arabic_Model_'+str(logs.get('val_accuracy'))+'.h5'
        if(logs.get('val_accuracy') > ACCURACY_THRESHOLD):   
          #print("\nWe have reached %2.2f%% accuracy, so we will stopping training." %(acc_thresh*100))   
          #self.model.stop_training = True
          self.model.save(fname)
          #from google.colab import files
          #files.download(fname)      


# The maximum number of words to be used. (most frequent)
MAX_NB_WORDS = vocab_len
# Max number of words in each complaint.
MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH = 50
# This is fixed.
EMBEDDING_DIM = 100

callbacks = myCallback()
def create_model(vocabulary_size, seq_len):
   

    model =  models.Sequential()
   
    model.add(Embedding(input_dim=MAX_NB_WORDS+1, output_dim=EMBEDDING_DIM, 
                        input_length=seq_len,mask_zero=True))
    
    model.add(GRU(units=64, return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Dropout(0.4))
    model.add(LSTM(units=50))  
   
    #model.add(LSTM(100)) 
    #model.add(Dropout(0.4))
    #Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(embedding_dim))
    
    #model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(128)))
    model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
    
    #model.add(Dense(200, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))

    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', 
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    
    model.summary()

    return model

model=create_model(MAX_NB_WORDS, MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH)

_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding_4 (Embedding)      (None, 50, 100)           2018600   
_________________________________________________________________
gru_2 (GRU)                  (None, 50, 64)            31680     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_10 (Dropout)         (None, 50, 64)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_6 (LSTM)                (None, 14)                4424      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_7 (Dense)              (None, 50)                750       
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_11 (Dropout)         (None, 50)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_8 (Dense)              (None, 4)                 204       
=================================================================
Total params: 2,055,658
Trainable params: 2,055,658
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________


model.fit(sequences, y_train, validation_data=(sequences_test, y_test), 
              epochs=25, batch_size=5, verbose=1,
              callbacks=[callbacks]
             )
```

It will be very helpful if i can get a sure shot to overcome overfitting.You can refer to below collab to see complete code:-

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/13N94kBKkHIX2TR5B_lETyuH1QTC5VuRf?usp=sharing

[image: Attching image of epochs]

Edit:---
I am now using pre-trained embedding layer which I created with gensim but now accuracy got decreased.Also,my record size is 4643.

Attaching below code:- in this 'English_dict.p' is the dictionary which i created using gensim.

```
embeddings_index=load(open('English_dict.p', 'rb'))

vocab_size=len(embeddings_index)+1

embedding_model = zeros((vocab_size, 100))

for word, i in embedding_matrix.word_index.items():
    embedding_vector = embeddings_index.get(word)
    if embedding_vector is not None:
        embedding_model[i] = embedding_vector

model.add(Embedding(input_dim=MAX_NB_WORDS, output_dim=EMBEDDING_DIM, 
                         weights=[embedding_model],trainable=False,
                        input_length=seq_len,mask_zero=True))


    Model: "sequential_2"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding_2 (Embedding)      (None, 50, 100)           2746300   
_________________________________________________________________
gru_2 (GRU)                  (None, 50, 64)            31680     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 50, 64)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_2 (LSTM)                (None, 128)               98816     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 50)                6450      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 4)                 204       
=================================================================
Total params: 2,883,450
Trainable params: 137,150
Non-trainable params: 2,746,300
_________________________________________________________________
```

Let me know if I am doing anything wrong. You can refer above collab for reference.

[image]

Comment: You said "80% for train and rest for validations." Do you mean the rest is for testing? The word "vaildation" is typically used for data which will determine tuning parameters, and this must be separate from the test set.

Comment: Yes i mean rest 20% is for testing.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no such thing as "a sure shot to overcome overfitting", it is always a problem of trial, error, and lots of research.

Comment: Yepp,that's why am not giving up yet...trying different ways to remove overfitting

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy could you please check the reason why accuracy getting down after using pre-embedded layer.Am not able to figure out the reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is classical overfitting. Why it is happening - the neural network has more than 2 million **trainable parameters** (2 055 658) while you have only 2600 records (you are using 80% for training). The NN is too big and instead of *generalization*, does *memorization*.

How to solve:

- start using [pre-trained word embeddings in a Keras model](https://blog.keras.io/using-pre-trained-word-embeddings-in-a-keras-model.html);
- use 90% of the data for training;
- the amount of training data, in theory, should be at least 2-3 less than a number of the **trainable parameters**;

Comment: For pre-trained, will creating word embedding via gensim will help? And then i can use that in model.

Comment: Technically, it doesn't matter how you will get word embeddings. Check by the link in the answer how to build `embedding_matrix` and don't forget set `trainable=False` for the Embedding layer.

Comment: as suggested, I used pre-trained embedding but accuracy got down. Added more details above. Please check.